# Images get from assets shows different size in different phone

Tags: android, imageview, size, assets

In my application i have some images that stored in assets like .The images may question,equation,answer etc..

```
App_name\assets\QuetionImage\PublicExamScientific\TEST1
App_name\assets\Answers\PublicExamScientific\Test1
App_name\assets\Answers\PublicExamScientific\Test2,etc..).
```

based on the type of question or image,I dynamically showed images to imageView.Now the problem is in some phones the images are too small and its not readable to the user.I used **wrap_content** for set the size of image.But in some phones its look nice.

Below code is what i did.

```
 ImageView img
 InputStream ims = getAssets().open("path");         
 Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
 img.setImageDrawable(d);
```

The images have size 200x45,150x42 etc
.How can i show images that readable in all phones.

Comment: Any purpose of placing the images in the assets, than considering the drawable folder?

Comment: the images are in different folders.just like  QuetionImage\PublicExamScientific\TEST1 ,QuetionImage\PublicExamScientific\TEST2,QuetionImage\PublicExamScientific\TEST4 etc.Here TEST1,TEST2,TEST3 are folders